# Why does Windows 8.1 prevent my wifi adapter from connecting to my 802.11n wireless network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I tried upgrading my mom's PC to Windows 8.1 and it wen't smooth for the most part except I could not connect to the wireless network anymore. The driver for the wireless adapter was installed (tried both microsoft's and TP-Link's) and networks were appearing, it just wouldn't connect. Took me awhile to figure out it wasn't connecting to the wireless n network, but would connect to g or b standard networks. The wifi adapter is supposed to be compatible with Windows 8 so I'm not sure why after the upgrade I'm unable to connect to the n standard network.

Wireless Adapter: TP-LINK TL-WN951N Wireless N300 Advanced PCI Adapter

Wireless Router: TP-LINK TL-WR941ND Wireless N300 Home Router

Router Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (03/25/13) std - build 21061

Comment: We'll need more information about your network setup.  What authentication and encryption settings is the WiFi setup to use (at the router)?  What have you tried?  Windows 8+ doesn't like WEP.

Comment: Are you unplugging your LAN when you try to connect via wifi?

Comment: I am using WPA2 Personal for security and that PC is never connected to LAN.

Comment: Have you tried shutting security off just for a test? If that would fix it then test out the different security protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not n? Check this at the command prompt.

```
> netsh wlan show interfaces
```

If it is not already 802.11n then check the wifi properties: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-802-11n-mode-wireless-connection-windows-8